# Fetch data from more than two tables using grails domain

Tags: grails

I have 3 table like v_ims_circuits , v_ims_productcodes and v_ims_domainmain  and i want to fetch data from this table using grails domain. 
Internally query should be build like below query using grails domain.

```
select cir.circuitname, cir.status, cir.oldname, cir.speed, null "Count of Subs",cir.productcode, cir.ordernr, 
cir.createuser, cir.createdate, cir.acquisitiondate,dom.domainname
from v_ims_circuits cir, v_ims_productcodes pc, v_ims_domainmain dom
where cir.productcode = pc.product
and pc.domainid = dom.id
and cir.circuitname = ?
```

Can any one help me on this.

Comment: These are view,and as they are view,they do not have any implicit dependencies.

Comment: you can run the raw sql, but what do your gorm objects look like?  You can probably traverse the object.  Need more information.

Answer (score 0):

GORM (and Hibernate) require a different mindset than SQL.  The first step is to create domain classes for your three tables; circuits, productcodes, and domainmain.  Chapter 7 of the Grails reference guide [Object Relational Mapping (GORM)](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html) is a good place to start.

Once your domain objects are built section 7.4 [Querying with GORM](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#querying) describes several ways you can fetch your data.  I also find the [Domain Classes Quick Reference](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/Usage.html) to be helpful.